# "During" or "In" in a sentence without a verb

Tags: prepositions

I'm correcting a list of parameter titles and explanations in a technical document where the prepositions of times have been used carelessly. The parameter titles mostly don't include verbs because the display doesn't have enough horizontal character space and has only one line whereas the explanation box has many lines. The title sentences have been built with the verbs in mind but later the verbs have been excluded to save space. I'm trying to save more space but don't want to misuse the prepositions.

My question is if I can use "in" instead of "during" in titles like these:

"Drum rotation speed in the tilting phase"

"Drum rotation speed during the tilting phase"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance you can use either *in* or *during* without changing the meaning. Although in a technical context, I'd personally have a slight preference for *during*.

There may be other cases where using *in* could lead to ambiguity due to its wider range of meanings. Compare the following;

*Items lost **in** packaging*

*Items lost **during** packaging*

I'd say the first is slightly ambiguous. Do we mean items lost inside some packaging material, or lost during a packaging process?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to be certain without an exhaustive list but the answer is probably yes - it's acceptable.

The fact that you have an explanation box should remove potential ambiguities although not of course grammatical errors. The 'rules' for title are a lot less strict than for body text so, in theory, you could shorten even further by using, for example something like

*Drum rotation speed - tilting phase*

It is a matter of style rather than grammar for titles.